# Which intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC) to use to verify the test-retest reliability of a questionnaire?

Tags: reliability, psychometrics, intraclass-correlation

I want to check the test-retest reliability of a questionnaire.

-A total of 300 adolescents from the same school (10 classes) participated in the study.
-The instrument was applied in two moments with an interval of 7 days.
-The same evaluator applied the questionnaire in both moments.
-The questionnaire generates a score (continuous variable).

Comment: How about the `psych::ICC` in r?